# Can a UITableView index jump to a row instead of a section?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, indexing

I have implemented a UITableView with only one giant section and now I need to implement an index to this UITableView (something like the contacts apps) however my index does not represent sections it represents rows. And as far as I know you can only jump to a section and not to a row with the index in tableview.

I don't want to add sections because then I'll have to add a section for each row, which would be kinda stupid.

So my question is: Is there any way to implement an index to a UITableView such that it when I tap on any part of the index it takes me to the relative row instead of section in the tableview?

I would probably endup writing a hack for this thing which a really wanna avoid and do it the way it should be done (if there is any such way) so any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement the sections and set their height to 0 in `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

Comment: is this really the way its suppose to be done..? i mean implementing a section for each row is an overkill don't you think??

Comment: No. I think that `UITableView`s are extremely efficient with these, and implementing it is probably a two-liner in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented it using a section for each row.

Answer (score 0):

It's not such a big hack. Just change rows for sections with one row. Move what you have in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. You have to slightly adapt `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to check the section you are in instead of the row and there you are.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i have ended up doing. I just didn't wanna do it because the concept of having hidden columns as many as i have rows in the tableview seemed like too expensive to me. I was thinking of writing a hack for something like getting the index number multiplying it with row height and the scrolling to that position or something like that. but i guess im too lazy for that :)  .thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: yeah i was thinking of using that if i did it manually. thanks